# Post request to airtable in Java

Tags: java, post, airtable

I am trying to replicate this Curl command in Java

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.airtable.com/v0/YOUR_BASE_ID/YOUR_TABLE_NAME \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "fields": {
        "Linked Field": ["Record1"]
    },
    "typecast": true 
}'
```

but i keep getting the following error:

```
{"type":"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY","message":"Could not parse request body"}
```

This is my code:

```
 String jsonRequest = "{" + 
        "fields" + ":" + "{" +
          "Shopping" + ":" + "record_id" +
          "Update" + ":" + "Apple" +
        "},"+
    
          "typecast" + ":" + "true" + 
    "}";

  public void createNewRecord() throws UnirestException{
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post("https://api.airtable.com/v0/"+environments.MAIN_BASE_API_KEY+"/"+ environments.TABLE_NAME)
      .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + environments.AIRTABLE_API_KEY)
      .body(jsonRequest)
      .asJson();
      System.out.println(response.getBody().toString());
    }
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `jsonRequest` does not look like valid JSON. I'm assuming that's also what the airtable API is trying to tell you with `Could not parse request body`. If you output or inspect (with a debugger) the contents of the `jsonRequest` variable (formatted):

```
{
    fields: {
        Shopping:record_id
        Update:Apple
    },
    typecast: true
}
```

You're at least missing a comma between `fields.shopping` and `fields.update`. The property names should also be in quotation marks. It should look something like this:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "Shopping": "record_id",
        "Update": "Apple"
    },
    "typecast": true
}
```

You could use something like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to help you validating your JSON.  But what will help more is not manually writing your JSON by concatenating strings but rather using Java objects which serialize  to JSON.

Recommended reading: [Intro to the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)